# Projects rebuilding due to inexplicable missing inputs

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I'm working on the build system of a product that contains several hundred C++ and C# projects in Visual Studio 2012. I’m trying to minimise the amount of unnecessary rebuilding that VS/MSBuild does after an SVN update (by fixing numerous little issues that makes MSBuild think a project needs a build when it really doesn’t).

After a lot of work I’ve achieved this, but I want to take it a step further. I want to be able to copy a preserved build environment from one build machine to another and still be able to do a minimal build on the new machine (I do have a good reason for this relating to patch building after release). This brought up a number of new issues, most of which were fixable. But despite the fact that the machines are identical (originally cloned from the same image), there are still a handful of projects that want to rebuild after being copied and I can’t figure them out.

One of these is a C++ project using CLR. According to Sysinternals Debug Viewer, the reason it wants to rebuild after the copy is:

```
[4520]  up to date is missing: 'C:\WINDOWS\ASSEMBLY\NATIVEIMAGES_V4.0.30319_64\SYSTEM\92AE81C9B2BA0AD6ED7B7450EE024DC9\SYSTEM.NI.DLL.AUX' 
[4520]  up to date is missing: 'C:\WINDOWS\ASSEMBLY\NATIVEIMAGES_V4.0.30319_64\SYSTEM.XML\6EDF8B6D912547891F6EA5F12307C003\SYSTEM.XML.NI.DLL.AUX'
```

This implies to me that the project is looking for things in the GAC as inputs to the build. This project does include System.Xml as an assembly reference, but it is referenced correctly (from the Framework directory). Since the two build machines are from the same image, everything is in the same places; of course, the GACs will be different, but the build shouldn’t look at the GAC at all. I can’t see anything in the project to indicate why it would look for this assembly in the GAC. The strange thing is, even the machine that originally did the build doesn’t have System.Xml 4.0 in the GAC, from what I can tell. After this project rebuilds one time on the new machine, it is fine… nothing changes in the GAC and subsequent incremental builds don’t trouble the project.

Can anyone think of a reason why this is happening to the project on the first build after being copied to a cloned machine? I’d love to get to the bottom of this so that I can use all available build machines for patch building.

**Edit:**
After some further investigation, I've found some clues. The xdcmake.read.1.tlog file in the build directory references those files mentioned above. For some reason Cygwin's grep doesn't find text inside this file, so my initial search didn't find it. Anyway, I was using Process Monitor to see what files Visual Studio accessed just before running the build and this was one of them.

xdcmake is meant to create code documentation xml files for your assembly... I can't understand why it would be trying to reference non-existing files. Further, I can't see why MSBuild is looking at the previous documentation log for inputs into the current incremental build. Seems to me like there's several bugs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd put the solution here in case someone else has this issue someday.

The xdcmake.read.1.tlog file in the build directory references those files mentioned above. xdcmake is meant to create code documentation xml files for your assembly. There must be some misconfiguration in some .Net framework assemblies (in the above case System.XML) that causes xdcmake to refer to them in the GAC instead of their proper location.

The solution is the delete references to GAC assemblies in all xdcmake.read files before an incremental build.